# Console app using NodeJS run on Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, console-application

My client has a .net console app that runs on Azure. They want to rewrite it using NodeJS. I am new to NodeJS. 
Is it feasible to create a console app using NodeJS and run it from Azure on schedule basis?

Comment: What does the console app do?

Comment: its reads content from azure sql db and creates a xml file and stores it in azure sql db

Answer (score 0):

You palpably want to use [`Azure Functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) to do that.

Quoting [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview):

> `Azure Functions` is a great solution for processing data, integrating systems, working with the internet-of-things (IoT), and building simple APIs and microservices. Consider Functions for tasks like image or order processing, file maintenance, or for any tasks that you want to run on a **schedule**. Functions can make development even more productive, and you can use your development language of choice, such as C#, F#, **Node.js**, Python or PHP.

You could use `TimerTrigger` template for your scenario. For an example, see [Create a function in Azure that is triggered by a timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer).

For reading content from Azure SQL Database, you'll need to install the npm package such as [`tedious`](https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious) or [`mssql`](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql). Please refer to U[se Node.js to connect and query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs) for more details.